# Convergence of series from a comparison of two series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}} \le \frac{y_{n+1}}{y_{n}}$ for sufficiently large $n$ and $\sum{y_n}$ is convergent then we have to show $\sum {x_n}$ is convergent.

I am kind of stuck in thinking. Any hint will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do your series  have positive terms?

Comment: Actually that's not stated ! any terms can be there

Comment: If the terms are positive this is a simple comparison. If the terms are not positive it's false - if the problem didn't specify the terms are positive it's wrong. Counterexample: $y_n=2^{-n}$, $x_n=(-1)^n$.